# Playback of rosbag with tf2-static transforms

Tags: ros, urdf, rosbag, tf2, tf-static

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS users,

I've got a robot setup where (most) of the static transforms are defined by an URDF (which results in tf2-static tfs).
During a testrun we recoded plenty of bag-files which where splitted after 1 min.

The static transforms are only contained in the 1. bagfile.

(1. Question) Is there a way to record splitted bagfiles with static-tfs, that the static-tfs are contained in each bag-file?

Furthermore (2. question), if the bagfile containing the static-tfs is played, they are only received by rviz (and probably other nodes as well) if rviz was started prior the playback of the bag-file, which seems for me like a bug.
Is there a solution to fix that (e.g. have rviz receiving the static-tfs even when its started lets say 2sec after the rosbag playback started)?

regards
Tobias

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255246/playback-of-rosbag-with-tf2-static-transforms/) by [Tobias Neumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5908/tobias-neumann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 179 on 2017-02-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For splitting bags, you'll likely want to use the rosbag API to push the static transform message into the separate bags.

A few other resources: http://answers.ros.org/question/207551/how-to-save-static-transforms-in-bag-files/ which links to https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/706 and some proposed solutions here: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/706

With respect to the startup order there are a few issues relating to latched values: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/685 https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/679 and https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/146 I'm not sure if any apply to your case without more details.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-22**:\

> And unfortunately rosbag doesn't support

does not support what? :)

**Comment by [Tobias Neumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5908/tobias-neumann/) on 2017-02-22**:
Thanks for the answer, it seems like a common problem ;)

For the 2. case, the relevant output from rosbag info:

```
/tf_static          2 msgs    : tf2_msgs/TFMessage              (2 connections)
```

**Comment by [Tobias Neumann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5908/tobias-neumann/) on 2017-02-22**:
So if I understand your linked topics correctly, https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/146 does apply and only the 2. msg is received by RVIZ (or other nodes) (the 1. is probably the URDF and the 2. is one tf2 static-tf-publisher)

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-02-22**:
@gvdhoorn sorry fragment from earlier draft.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-02-22**:
@ToXeR if you have two static transform publishers that can be a problem with rosbag as it will only latch one on playback.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good news for your first question:

In `Noetic`, [this PR](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1850) has been merged and thus you can do the following:

```
rosbag record -a --repeat-latched --duration 5 --split
```

Note, some issues with the `--repeat-latched` option will hopefully be resolved by [this PR](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/2201).

---

Originally posted by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) with karma: 212 on 2022-01-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1